# Why do conversions of Float to Double fail at runtime?

Tags: swift, casting, floating-point, type-conversion

I have the following code:

```
func roughlyEq<T: FloatingPoint>(_ a: T, _ b: T) -> Bool {
  return abs(a - b) < (0.01 as! T)
}
```

When I invoke it with arguments of type Float, I get a crash at runtime:

```
Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Double' (0x10043e6a8) to 'Swift.Float' (0x10043e5e0)
```

This makes no sense -- 0.01 can indeed be converted to Float, say when I write `Float(0.01)`. Why is this error happening?

The opposite direction fails, too:

```
Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Float' (0x1004ea5e0) to 'Swift.Double' (0x1004ea6a8).
```

How do I get this method to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Alexander already said, you cannot forcefully cast from `Double`
to `Float`. The literal constant `0.01` has type `Double` in your
function, and the cast `as! T` fails if `T` is `Float`

A simple solution is to define the function for `BinaryFloatingPoint`
instead, which describes a "binary floating point type" and extends the `FloatingPoint` protocol.
All the usual floating point types (`Float`, `Double` and
`CGFloat`) conform to `BinaryFloatingPoint`.
Since `BinaryFloatingPoint` also inherits from 
`ExpressibleByFloatLiteral`, you can now compare against the
`0.01` literal:

```
func roughlyEq<T: BinaryFloatingPoint>(_ a: T, _ b: T) -> Bool {
    return abs(a - b) < 0.01
}
```

Here the type of `0.01` is inferred from the context as `T`.

Or as a protocol extension method:

```
extension BinaryFloatingPoint {
    func roughlyEq(_ other: Self) -> Bool {
        return abs(self - other) < 0.01
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this possible to define as a member function, so that I can do a.roughlyEq(b), ideally for different floating-point types a and b, or at least for the same type? Presumably, in the former case, we'll have to find a way to convert both to the same type, perhaps via NSNumber.

Comment: @VaddadiKartick: See updated answer. If you want to compare different floating-point types then you probably have to define a custom protocol (as in Alexander's answer) which allows to convert all operands to a common type.

Comment: Is there a way to create a Double with a generic argument type? I don't mind if it's slower because of reflection or something else dynamic.

Comment: @VaddadiKartick: Sorry, I do not understand your question.

Comment: I mean invoke Double's init() method with an argument that's a generic type T, not Float or Double. Perhaps using reflection. As long as it's valid at runtime, I don't want the compiler to get in the way.

Answer (score 2):

Because `Double` and `Float` are completely unrelated types. i.e. `Double` is not a class/protocol that's a super type of `Float` and vice versa.

Note that just because there exist initializers to convert back and forth between `Double` and `Float`, doesn't mean that you can cast back and forth between them.

The `FloatingPoint` protocol does a good job of abstracting the behaviour of floating point types, and defines most things entirely in terms of `Self`, and never under the assumption that `Double` or `Float` (or any concrete type, for that matter) is a more privileged or special `Self` type than any other.

I don't think there's a way to extend `FloatingPoint` with a generic function for this, because `Float` and `Double` operations are intrinsically non-generic (in that they're bound to concrete types, and the hardware that implements them).

Here's how I would do this:

```
protocol DoubleOrFloat: FloatingPoint, ExpressibleByFloatLiteral {}
extension Float: DoubleOrFloat {}
extension Double: DoubleOrFloat {}


extension DoubleOrFloat {
    func roughlyEquals(_ other: Self) -> Bool {
        let closeEnoughThreshold: Self = 0.01
        return abs(self - other) < closeEnoughThreshold
    }
}
```

The key line is `let closeEnoughThreshold: Self = 0.01`. It's possible because `DoubleOrFloat` is a subtype of `ExpressibleByFloatLiteral`, so it's known that the float literal `0.01` can be converted to `Self` (given that it's known that `Self` is `DoubleOrFloat`, which implies `ExpressibleByFloatLiteral`).